# Barra fixa no rodapé em CSS não exibe corretamente no iPad

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma div para ficar no rodapé, porém quando acesso pelo IPAD ele cria uma distância da última DIV com a DIV fixa do rodapé.

**CSS:**

```
.fixo-modelo-3-1 {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 43px;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color:#FFFE62;
}
```

Segue link da página:

http://www.roteirodoimovel.com.br/modelos/3/teste.php

Comment: está usando bootstrap?

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva não.

Comment: Gladison, olha eu aqui de novo.
Cara acho que você aprenderia muito com esse artigo da Dani Gerrato: http://tableless.com.br/design-responsivo-na-pratica-do-rascunho-ao-digita/